# Time between flights at Athens Airport

Tags: short-connections, connecting-flights, athens, ath

We have our flight on Emirates 210 arriving at Athens at 16:05 and then have a flight on Olympic Air (operated by Aegean Air) at 19:10. Is the time sufficient to board the Olympic Air. I have two different tickets. Kindly advise

Comment: Do you have checked bags?  Is your connecting flight within or outside Schengen?

Comment: Remember: unless your ticket is changeable/refundable and you warn them before the check-in deadline, if you miss your flight, you’ll have to book and pay for a new ticket, which can be quite expensive (and/or difficult, if the flights are busy) at the last minute. If there’s a return flight on that ticket, it may be cancelled as well. If you need to stay overnight, you’ll have to book and pay for the hotel and meals as well. You should probably look into travel insurance that covers this.

Comment: Also, remember that you will need a Schengen visa for this, even if you are transiting from outside to outside of the Schengen Area, as you will need to enter it to reclaim your bags and check them again.

Comment: Is your Olympic Air flight destination within Greece? When are you travelling (July/August are peak holiday months)? If the inbound flight is late, and if you have to collect /re-check luggage and go through security to reach your connecting flight, things could go wrong eg you may make the checkin time but miss the gate closure deadline. Also remember that strikes in Greece are quite common https://www.tripsavvy.com/how-strikes-affect-travel-to-greece-1526232

Answer (score 4):

> Is the time sufficient to board the Olympic Air.

If the flight is not late, for sure. ATH is not big, you will be at check in by 17:00-17:30 and your check in closes 30 minutes before the flight (https://www.olympicair.com/en/Info/Checkin/check-in-times) so you have an hour buffer.

> I have two different tickets. Kindly advise

Well, since you are asking for my advice. I am doing unprotected connections quite often and I always book them in such a fashion that if I am on the next plane (in this case, next day) I still can catch my connecting flight. I check into a hotel near (or, if there is one, then *inside* -- yay for yotel) the airport. Peeking at a site like https://www.airportia.com/flights/ek210/newark/athens/ you can see it is usually on time or less than 30 minutes late ... except July 17 when it happened to be more than three hours late. If your plane is very late, to make things worse, since I presume you are not well experienced in these matters you are very likely to spend the nine hour flight fretting over what happens: nothing much, you buy a new plane ticket. Which can be quite expensive, of course. Now, most Emirates planes have wifi so if you are very late once airborne begin to look for a new ticket. (But then again, never fully rely on your plane having wifi.)

[image]